# Apple Mach-O Link Error in unity project

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, x86-64, il2cpp

I've receive the a unity game project, which might need to integrate in our future app. the source is base on Xcode 9 & swift 4, when I try to build, I've got this Apple Mach-O Link Error as in the follow picture :

Solutions that I've try:

1.change build setting -> Architectures to armv7 and build active architecture YES. but it doesn't work.

2. change build setting -> Architectures to standard architecture. and YES to Build Active Architecture Only for DEBUG

3.try to add libiPhone-lib.a in the Link Binary With Libraries. it doesn't work neither.

4.try to add libil2cpp folder in project, it doesn't work neither.

I have no idea about those error and no experience on develop unity project, Please let me know if you have any idea. Screenshot of error:

[image]

Comment: It looks like you are missing the architecture that you are targeting. Notice how the top warning says that it's ignoring the libiPhone-lib.a? It looks like you are trying to build for x86_64, but trying to say to build for armv7 in the xcode project. What platform are you targeting in Unity? What is the actual destination of the project (OSX / iOS)?

Comment: it's an iOS project @Zenel

Comment: Is the unity project targeting iOS too, or standalone? Something is telling the project to build as x86_64.